# Differentiate functions when overloading

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, overloading

I'm writing two functions with the same name (and with similar parameters):
The first one only takes a variable amount of integer parameters (minimum one).
The second one takes a variable amount of `struct coordinate` as parameters (again minimum one).
The `struct coordinate` can be constructed from both `int` and `std::vector<int>`, so the second one can in that way also take `int` and `std::vector<int>`.
The problem is that if the first parameter to the second function is an `int` then the compilation fails.
Is it possible to make the third line in `main()` call the other `tmp` function?
My current implementation is listed below.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    tmp(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);                   // OK! First function calls 'single'
    tmp(std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3}, 4, 5); // OK! Second function calls 'multi'
    tmp(1, std::vector<int>{2, 3}, 4);    // Compilation error! First function calls 'single'

    return 0;
}
```

Compiler output:

```
prog.cpp: In instantiation of ‘std::vector<int> tmp(int, types ...) [with types = {std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, int}]’:
prog.cpp:58:34:   required from here
prog.cpp:29:23: error: no matching function for call to ‘single(std::vector<int>&, std::vector<int>&, int&)’
  single(list, ints ...);
                       ^
prog.cpp:29:23: note: candidates are:
prog.cpp:12:6: note: void single(std::vector<int>&, int)
 void single(std::vector<int>& list, int first)
      ^
prog.cpp:12:6: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided
prog.cpp:18:6: note: template<class ... types> void single(std::vector<int>&, int, types ...)
 void single(std::vector<int>& list, int first, types ... ints)
      ^
prog.cpp:18:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cpp:29:23: note:   cannot convert ‘ints#0’ (type ‘std::vector<int>’) to type ‘int’
  single(list, ints ...);
                       ^
```

My current implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct coordinate
{
    std::vector<int> c;

    coordinate(std::vector<int> A) : c(A) {}
    coordinate(int A) : c{A} {}
};

// Function to end the recursive call to single
void single(std::vector<int>& list, int first)
{
    list.push_back(first);
}

// Recursive function to store the parameters (only int)
template <typename... types>
void single(std::vector<int>& list, int first, types ... ints)
{
    list.push_back(first);
    single(list, ints ...);
}

// 'First' function
template <typename... types>
std::vector<int> tmp(int i, types ... ints)
{
    std::vector<int> list;
    list.push_back(i);
    single(list, ints ...);
    return list;
}

// Function to end the recursive call to multi
void multi(std::vector<std::vector<int> >& list, coordinate first)
{
    list.push_back(first.c);
}

// Recursive function for storing the parameters (only 'coordinate')
template <typename... types>
void multi(std::vector<std::vector<int> >& list, coordinate first, types ... coords)
{
    list.push_back(first.c);
    multi(list, coords ...);
}

// 'Second' function
template <typename... types>
std::vector<std::vector<int> > tmp(coordinate i, types ... coords)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > list;
    list.push_back(i.c);
    multi(list, coords ...);
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, based on my new understanding from the comment you want something like this:

```
template <typename... Args>
typename std::enable_if<all_ints<Args...>::value>::type
tmp(Args... args) {
   // the all integer version
}

template <typename... Args>
typename std::enable_if<!all_ints<Args...>::value>::type
tmp(Args... args) {
   // the coordinate version
}
```

Then you just need to write the type trait to check if everything is an integer.

```
template <typename... T>
struct all_ints : std::true_type { };

template <typename T, typename... Rest>
struct all_ints<T, Rest...>
: std::integral_constant<bool, 
      std::is_integral<T>::value && all_ints<Rest...>::value>
{ }
```

I used `std::is_integal` to handle all the integer types. If you really want explicitly `int`, you can fix it.

Comment: I am looking for some way to have the three calls to `tmp` stay the same, and only change the implementation. In order to ensure that the `tmp` function is part of a API with that call 'signature'.

Comment: What is it you want the function to do? Do one thing if all the arguments are `int`s and another if they're not all `int`s?

Comment: In a nutshell; yes. While the amount of parameters is variable.

Comment: @Jonas OK new answer.

Comment: You make the return type a second type parameter to enable_if:  `std::enable_if<all_ints<Args...>::value, std::vector<int>>::type`.  The default second type arg to `enable_if` is `void`.

Comment: @Barry I get an error when I compile:
prog.cpp:19:8: error: redeclared with 2 template parameters
 struct all_ints : std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_integral<T>::value && all_ints<Rest ...>::value> { };
        ^
prog.cpp:13:8: note: previous declaration 'template<class ... T> struct all_ints' used 1 template parameter
 struct all_ints : std::true_type { };
        ^